# Kendo UI - Progress Bar - Orientation

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-progressbar

I am working with the Kendo UI Progress Bar.

I need to use a vertical progress bar to illustrate a users progress as they complete the form.

My progress bar is as follows:

```
 var pb = $("#profileCompleteness").kendoProgressBar({
                type: "chunk",
                chunkCount: xChunkCount,
                min: 0,
                max: xChunkCount,
                value: 0,
                orientation: "vertical"
            }).data("kendoProgressBar");
```

I'm having one issue at this point.
The progress bar increments/chunks from **bottom to top**. I need it to increment/chunk from **top to bottom**.

Does anyone know if there is a way to flip the vertical orientation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the "reverse" option of the widget:

- [reverse option](http://docs.telerik.com/KENDO-UI/api/javascript/ui/progressbar#configuration-reverse)

Comment: Thanks! I did not see that.